# Registry deprecated in magento 2.3, How to set data without Registry?

Tags: magento2.3.3, registry, deprecated

I am creating a custom blog, in which I use the `\Magento\Framework\Registry` and it is deprecated.

I searched for solution but I could only find the way to get the data without registry.

Is there's any way to **set data without registry**?

Comment: you can use custom var session for that

Comment: Did you fix this, Haerriz?

Comment: Nope haven't found a fix for it yet @PKTG

Comment: Did you try the articles in the link in the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read this article with discussion in the comments(!) -

https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/alternatives-for-deprecated-registry-class-magento-2-3/

Shortly: don't use session, use own class for registry.

As example: https://github.com/Vinai/module-current-product-example

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will helpful to you

you can use like that in helper function or block function

and set your custom variable in that

```
public function sessionData()
    {
        $this->session->setData('custom', 'value');
        $this->session->getData('custom');
        $this->session->unsetData('custom');
    }
```